# Meteor. Error after update to 1.9 from 1.8.3

Tags: meteor

I updated the Meteor to 1.9 with all packages(meteor/npm). The bcrypt was already installed.

I followed and executed all migration steps. Despite that I got the follow errors:

(Important to note if I downgrade to 1.8.3 everything works fine)

What is going wrong?

```
W20200720-17:39:36.075(3)? (STDERR) Note: you are using a pure-JavaScript implementation of bcrypt.
W20200720-17:39:36.078(3)? (STDERR) While this implementation will work correctly, it is known to be
W20200720-17:39:36.079(3)? (STDERR) approximately three times slower than the native implementation.
W20200720-17:39:36.079(3)? (STDERR) In order to use the native implementation instead, run
W20200720-17:39:36.080(3)? (STDERR) 
W20200720-17:39:36.080(3)? (STDERR)   meteor npm install --save bcrypt
W20200720-17:39:36.080(3)? (STDERR) 
W20200720-17:39:36.081(3)? (STDERR) in the root directory of your application.
=> Exited with code: 7
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Start meteor all logs:

```
backend $ meteor
[[[[[ ~/job/meteor/backend ]]]]]              

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Meteor 1.10.2 is available. Update this project with 'meteor update'.
WARNING: npm peer requirements (for juliancwirko:postcss) not installed:
 - postcss@7.0.6 installed, postcss@^6.0.22 needed
 - postcss-load-config@2.0.0 installed, postcss-load-config@^1.2.0 needed

Read more about installing npm peer dependencies:
  http://guide.meteor.com/using-packages.html#peer-npm-dependencies

=> Started MongoDB.                           
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update caniuse-lite browserslist`
W20200722-11:50:38.504(3)? (STDERR) Note: you are using a pure-JavaScript implementation of bcrypt.
W20200722-11:50:38.538(3)? (STDERR) While this implementation will work correctly, it is known to be
W20200722-11:50:38.539(3)? (STDERR) approximately three times slower than the native implementation.
W20200722-11:50:38.539(3)? (STDERR) In order to use the native implementation instead, run
W20200722-11:50:38.539(3)? (STDERR) 
W20200722-11:50:38.540(3)? (STDERR)   meteor npm install --save bcrypt
W20200722-11:50:38.540(3)? (STDERR) 
W20200722-11:50:38.540(3)? (STDERR) in the root directory of your application.
=> Exited with code: 7
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: Did you try `meteor reset` and delete all `node_modules` then reinstall?

Comment: This shouldn't crash the process, since it's just a warning note. Can you edit with the full logs you get from running `meteor`, since I suspect there's something else wrong here?

Comment: @Jankapunkt. Yes.

Comment: @FredStark ok. Soon

Comment: Funnily enough, I think the error is a warning and the warning is an error. Try installing the peer dependencies: `postcss` and `postcss-load-config`

Comment: @FredStark thank you very much for answers. I installed. Did not help